# HOW TO MERGE SCREEN AND WIDGET IN KIVY 1.4

Tags: python, widget, kivy, screen

I want to add widgets to different screens in the kivy 1.10.0 and I want use those ids in the python file. But i am not getting exact procedure for doing this.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please try sth first and then we can help you.

Comment: Kivy 1.4? Just curious, why not use kivy 1.10, the official stable release.